# requestWhenInUseAuthorization in iOS 8 and wait until user responds

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am trying to fetch user's location using `CLLocationManager`. Here is my simple code:

```
if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        // iOS8+
        // Sending a message to avoid compile time error
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)
                                                   to:self.locationManager
                                                 from:self
                                             forEvent:nil];
        CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

        if (authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ||
            authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
            authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {

            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }else{
            [self removeIndicatorView];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is, the code keep executing even the alert is on top. I want to stop the execution until user press allow or deny before updating location. 
How I can do it?

I don't want to use delay or timer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the delegate method [locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:](http://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html) to run your code when the user allows or disallows the location request.